# C# EntityFramework effective way of getting data (OrderBy + Distinct)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get distinct users from DB with latest loggin time. My code works but it takes about 20s to finnish. Can I optimize my code?

```
var usersFromDb = _Context.Users
    .OrderByDescending(u => u.Time)
    .DistinctBy(u => u.ID).ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Client { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    }
```

This table has like 100k records

Comment: could you attach your model?

Comment: Have you looked into adding the corresponding indexes on your table?

Comment: the ID field is primary key in table?

Comment: If `DistinctBy` method used is from MoreLINQ, then it executes in memory. You'd probably need to use `GroupBy` + `OrderDescending` + `FirstOrDefault` in order to get the whole thing in database. Also, if `ID` is not the PK, then what is the PK (EF cannot work w/o PK)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add nonclustered index for the `Time` field to optimize OrderBy operation. For example, you can just change your model like this

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Client { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

}
```

and apply a migration to DB on next. Other way, you can create an index in the database without change a EF model, just execute next sql query

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Time ON Users (Time);
```

Defining index on sort column improve performance results.

---

**As `ID` is not a primary key**, you should create a covering index from two column to maximize performance query

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Time ON Users (Time, ID);
```

Comment: By adding an index to Time column the response time reduced from ~20s to ~10s. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, the users should already have unique Id, so the distinct is redundant.

I would hope the SQL optimiser would know that if it's the Clustered Index, but you could try removing it.

Do you need to return all users? Are you using lazy loading? You might be pulling back the client data also, so it might be worth checking SQL Server profiler to see what is happening.

You could also just return the fields you need:

```
var usersFromDb = _Context.Users
    .Select(u => new MyUser
        {
            Id = u.ID,
            Name = u.Name,
            Time = u.Time
        }).
    .OrderByDescending(u => u.Time)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It might sounds stupid and you might think it has no sense but in this case the same ID can appear multiple times (that's why I need distnict). I was not the designer of this database. This table has around 100k records.

Comment: Then your Id needs an index to improve access.

You could also try grouping by the Id, and taking the Max date.

The best thing to do in any case where you need to try different Linq quickly is to install LinqPad. Make it your friend, and it will serve you well. https://www.linqpad.net/